# iOS certified or complaint Bluetooth (BLE) USB smart dongle

Tags: ios, ios-bluetooth

I'm looking for any apple/iOS certified USB BT smart dongle available in the market.
I was searching google for past few days but unsuccessful in finding the same
Can anybody let me know if anybody having any idea on the same?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? If you want to test CoreBluetooth in the Simulator, that is no longer supported.

Comment: Looking for a USB BT smart dongle which can transfer the data from iOS App to the target where the BT smart dongle is connected to as an HID event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm posting my own answer here, we have not found an iOS certified USB dongle.
But TI CC254XX series of BT dongles shall work for BLE and support the profiles.

HID is also supported, they have some examples in their package which shall make your life easy when developing any app

Hope this helps.